# Why it's giving me that GROUP BY Description_lenght_buckets as Invalid Column name?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN LEN(b.app_desc) < 500 THEN 'Short'
WHEN LEN(b.app_desc) BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 'Medium'
ELSE 'Long'
END AS Description_lenght_buckets, AVG(a.user_rating) AS Avg_rating
FROM AppleStore AS a
JOIN appleStore_description AS b
ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY Description_lenght_buckets
ORDER BY Avg_rating
```

The only way I tried is to create new column using ALTER then to GROUP BY, then it will work.

Is it the only way for this code to work is to use ALTER??

Comment: You can't use aliases in a group by clause

Comment: Please show sample data and the expected result

Comment: You are not using SQLite: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qmzxRKKiULYiuXeCRgTXhx/0. Why didn't you chose the correct tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via subselecting:

```
SELECT Description_lenght_buckets, AVG(user_rating) AS Avg_rating
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LENGTH(b.app_desc) < 500 THEN 'Short'
        WHEN LENGTH(b.app_desc) BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 'Medium'
        ELSE 'Long'
    END AS Description_lenght_buckets, user_rating
    FROM AppleStore AS a
    JOIN appleStore_description AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
) t
GROUP BY Description_lenght_buckets
ORDER BY AVG(user_rating);
```

Explanation: Your subselect selects the individual records you want to aggregate.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/79ba4/1

Comment: @mohannadmabrouk happy to help.